# Eigen Matrix sum with NANs

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an Eigen Matrix A which includes NAN values. I want to get the sum of differences of this matrix to multiple other matrices.

```
double getDistance(const Eigen::MatrixXf& from, const Eigen::MatrixXf& to)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf difference = (to - from).cwiseAbs2();

    difference = difference.unaryExpr([](float v, double& sum)
    { return std::isnan(v) ? 0.0f : v;});

    double distance = difference.sum();

    return distance;
}

std::vector<double> getDistances(const std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf>& from, const Eigen::MatrixXf& to)
{
    std::vector<double> distances;
    for (int i = 0; i < from.size(); ++i)
    {
       distances.push_back(getDistance(from[i], to));
    }
    return distances;
}
```

Right now I need to remove the NANs of `difference` every single time and then take the sum.
I was thinking about doing my own sum function which skips NANs.
Is there an elegant way to do this?

Does `unaryExpr` work for summing up where we need an "out parameter"?

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question. Why do you have nan values to begin with? nan in floats is a debug indication of bad inputs. You really should take a step back and eliminate them at the point where they are created instead of dealing with them.

Comment: The matrix represents sensor input (Kinect like depth sensor) and actually represents bad inputs (not measurable distance) from the sensor.
So no way to get rid of them, and I actually want them there to easily distinguish that from valid data.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to follow starmole recommendation first, but to answer the question isNaN and select are for you:

```
return (to-from).array().isNaN().select(0,to-from).squaredNorm();
```

Comment: Will `to - from` be calculated twice in this case?

Comment: That depends on the compiler ability to remove the duplicate within the fused loop. Anyway, since the operation is very cheap, it's likely better to do it twice than evaluating it in a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of [Eigen 3.4](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.4), handling [NaN propagation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.4#Improvement_to_NaN_propagation) got improved.